# How to show more lines in wordpress homepage?

Tags: wordpress

On my Wordpress homepage, the post is showing only one line of description. How do I add new lines?

[image: post screenshot]

I want to show more lines. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below shared code in your theme function.php file:-

```
/**
 * Filter the except length to 100 words.
 *
 * @param int $length Excerpt length.
 * @return int (Maybe) modified excerpt length.
 */
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: thank you can you please tell me how to edit home page <title>Site title - Tag line</title> i just want to remove "-"